# Recalculating Normals Of Edited Heightmap

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monogame, normals

I have a terrain editor written in C# and Monogame. Once I edit the terrain, I would like to only recalculate the normals for the vertices associated with the triangles that actually changed position. However, I am running into an issue where there is always a "ring" around the edited area that has normals that don't seem to match up. If I recalculate all normals for the mesh after editing the terrain, it looks correct.

Here is an image showing the normals only being calculated on triangles affected[image: Only Verts Affected]

Here is an image of what it should look like. The normals here are calculated the same exact way, just for every vertex instead of only the vertices associated with the triangle
[image]

Here is how I am currently recalculating the normals for only vertices associated with the triangles that actually changed

```
        private void RecalculateNormals(Terrain terrain, List<int> uniqueVertexIndex)
        {
            List<int[]> totalTriangles = new List<int[]>();
            List<int> verticesToNormalize = new List<int>();
            foreach (int vertexIndex in uniqueVertexIndex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Vertex Position Changed: " + vertexIndex);
                foreach (int[] triangle in terrain.Collider.lookupTrianglesAttachedToVertex(vertexIndex))
                {
                    bool skip = false;
                    foreach (int[] testTriangle in totalTriangles)
                        if (triangle[0] == testTriangle[0])
                        {
                            skip = true;
                        }
                    if (!skip)
                    {
                        totalTriangles.Add(triangle);
                        foreach (int index in triangle)
                        {
                            if (!verticesToNormalize.Contains(terrain.Mesh.Indices[index]))
                            {
                                verticesToNormalize.Add(terrain.Mesh.Indices[index]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
 
            foreach (int vertex in verticesToNormalize)
            {
                terrain.Mesh.Vertices[vertex].Normal = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                Console.WriteLine("Vertex Updating: " + vertex);
            }
 
            foreach (int[] triangle in totalTriangles)
            {
                int index1 = terrain.Mesh.Indices[triangle[0]];
                int index2 = terrain.Mesh.Indices[triangle[1]];
                int index3 = terrain.Mesh.Indices[triangle[2]];
                Vector3 side1 = terrain.Mesh.Vertices[index3].Position - terrain.Mesh.Vertices[index2].Position;
                Vector3 side2 = terrain.Mesh.Vertices[index2].Position - terrain.Mesh.Vertices[index1].Position;
                Vector3 normal = Vector3.Cross(side1, side2);
            
                terrain.Mesh.Vertices[index1].Normal += normal;
                terrain.Mesh.Vertices[index2].Normal += normal;
                terrain.Mesh.Vertices[index3].Normal += normal;
 
                Console.WriteLine("Recalculated Normals on Triangle: " + triangle[0] + " " + index1 + " | " + triangle[1] + " " + index2 + " | " + triangle[2] + " " + index3);
 
            }
 
            foreach (int vertex in verticesToNormalize)
               terrain.Mesh.Vertices[vertex].Normal.Normalize();
 
        }
```

Here is a pastebin with the more of relevant code. I'm not sure what I'm missing here or if I'm misunderstanding something about the way normals are calculated: https://pastebin.com/KTLq2CY1

[EDIT]

After working with it a bit more I realized I wasn't accounting for all of the triangles for vertices that didn't change position, but have corrected that now in the following code. I was also adding the normals to vertices that didn't change, which didn't need to happen so I culled those from the normal additions and everything is working great now!

```
        private void RecalculateNormals(Terrain terrain, List<int> uniqueVertexIndex)
        {
            List<int[]> totalTriangles = new List<int[]>();
            List<int> verticesToNormalize = new List<int>();
            foreach (int vertexIndex in uniqueVertexIndex)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Selected Vertex: {0}", vertexIndex);
                foreach (int[] triangle in terrain.Collider.lookupTrianglesAttachedToVertex(vertexIndex))
                {
                    bool skip = false;
                    foreach (int[] testTriangle in totalTriangles)
                        {
                            if (testTriangle[0] == triangle[0])
                            {
                                skip = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!skip)
                        {
                            totalTriangles.Add(triangle);
                        }
                    foreach (int index in triangle)
                    {
                        if (!verticesToNormalize.Contains(terrain.Mesh.Indices[index]))
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine("Adding Vertex: " + terrain.Mesh.Indices[index]);
                            verticesToNormalize.Add(terrain.Mesh.Indices[index]);
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (int vertex in verticesToNormalize)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Vertex To Update: {0}", vertex);
                foreach (int[] triangle in terrain.Collider.lookupTrianglesAttachedToVertex(vertex))
                {
                    bool skip = false;
                    foreach (int[] testTriangle in totalTriangles)
                    {
                        if (testTriangle[0] == triangle[0])
                            skip = true; //Console.WriteLine("Skipping Triangle: {0} | Compared to Existing Triangle: {1}", triangle[0], testTriangle[0]);
                    }

                    if (!skip)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("Not Skipping Triangle {0}", triangle[0]);
                        totalTriangles.Add(triangle);
                    }
                }
            }

            Dictionary<int,int> NormalUpdateCount = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            foreach (int vertex in verticesToNormalize)
            {
                terrain.Mesh.Vertices[vertex].Normal = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                //Console.WriteLine("Vertex Updating: " + vertex);
                NormalUpdateCount.Add(vertex, 0);
            }

            foreach (int[] triangle in totalTriangles)
            {
                
                int index1 = terrain.Mesh.Indices[triangle[0]];
                int index2 = terrain.Mesh.Indices[triangle[1]];
                int index3 = terrain.Mesh.Indices[triangle[2]];
                Vector3 side1 = terrain.Mesh.Vertices[index3].Position - terrain.Mesh.Vertices[index2].Position;
                Vector3 side2 = terrain.Mesh.Vertices[index2].Position - terrain.Mesh.Vertices[index1].Position;
                Vector3 normal = Vector3.Cross(side1, side2);

                // terrain.Mesh.Vertices[index1].Normal += normal;
                // terrain.Mesh.Vertices[index2].Normal += normal;
                // terrain.Mesh.Vertices[index3].Normal += normal;

                if (verticesToNormalize.Contains(index1))
                {
                    NormalUpdateCount[index1] += 1;
                    terrain.Mesh.Vertices[index1].Normal += normal;
                } 
                if (verticesToNormalize.Contains(index2))
                {
                    NormalUpdateCount[index2] += 1;
                    terrain.Mesh.Vertices[index2].Normal += normal;
                }
                if (verticesToNormalize.Contains(index3))
                {
                    NormalUpdateCount[index3] += 1;
                    terrain.Mesh.Vertices[index3].Normal += normal;
                }
            }

            // foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in NormalUpdateCount)
            // {
            //     Console.WriteLine("Vertex {0} updated with {1} normal additions", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            // }

            foreach (int vertex in verticesToNormalize)
            {
               terrain.Mesh.Vertices[vertex].Normal.Normalize();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this is in the edit. I needed to calculate the normals based on all 6 triangles for each vertex that was adjacent to any vertex that moved. I also needed to cull the addition of the normals for vertices that weren't adjacent, otherwise they would get 2 normals added to them causing distortion as well.